# Limiting Values for Calendar DatePicker

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery

Has anybody tried manipulating the DatePicker in Joomla? For example, In my datepicker, I am only able to select the date not greater than or equal than the current date, or from the datepicker, based on the current date, I will subtract days. For example, today is March 2, 2015. I will subtract 10 days from it, Maximum selectable date is February 23, 2015.

Does joomla have something to do with this? Or is this achievable in javascript?

I have followed this link from jQuery :

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

I tried this code for the datepicker after reading the guide from the link above but to no avail, it does not work. It's really frustrating. This is a basic functionality that Joomla should have.

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( ".datecalendar" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the reference below, and by following this link :
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max.

But because of this, I cannot use the calendar type as the form field for my date fields. I need to use "text" as their type.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js">

I used one of my fields as an example, and it worked. except it was using a different UI Calendar than joomla's default calendar

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#jform_start_date").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "0" });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some options you can control using [Calendar.setup](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/media/system/js/calendar-setup-uncompressed.js). But if you need more customization you will need [to create a custom field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) for that (may be with your own calendar script).

Comment: is creating a custom field the best option for this? I really just want to limit the minimum and maximum date input.